# Can we position the model in ARCore Augmented face?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am actually following google's ARcore AugmentedFaces sample code.

What I am trying to achieve is to make my 3d object appear on top of my face.

I am using the following line to code to do that.

```
AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
faceNode.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0.0f,5.1f,0.0f));
```

But it doesn't work like that. I was not able to find any samples related to this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No. I don't have a working solution.